# Unable to decode stream Error when i return bitmap to hashmap after scaling it

Tags: android, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

In my program i was showing images from SD card to the listview using SimpleAdapter but i was getting OutofMemory and File too large error so i was trying to scale image to low size for that i created a separate class file to do this

**ThumbCreator.class**

```
public Bitmap convertIntoThumb(String file_uri,String file_name)
{
    try
    {

    File f = new File(file_uri, file_name+".jpg");

    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

    //The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale=1;
    while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale*=2;

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);

    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(file_uri+"THUMB1_"+file_name+".jpg"));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOutStream);

    fOutStream.flush();
    fOutStream.close();

    return bitmap;
}


catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    // TODO: handle exception
    return null;
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO: handle exception
    return null;
}

}
```

I return this bitmap to my main activity class in the hashmap.put() method directly as bellow

**Main.class**

```
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>();


    //***adding receipts from particular record to cursor.
    cursor = sqldb.rawQuery("select * from table_1 where record_name = '"+record_name+"'",null);
    curso.moveToFirst();

    while (curso.isAfterLast()!=true) 
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> hashmap_temp = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        hashmap_temp.put("name", cursor_receipt.getString(1));


        if(cursor.getString(7).toString() != "")
        {
            hashmap_temp.put("image",thumbcreator.convertIntoThumb(img_path_new,cursor_receipt.getString(7)));

        }

        list.add(hashmap_temp);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    SimpleAdapter adptr_list;

    adptr_list = new SimpleAdapter(context_receipt, list, R.layout.activity_textview_receipt, new String[]{"image","name"},new int[]{R.id.img_receipt,R.id.tv_name});

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(adptr_list);
```

The error i am getting is

```
01-28 16:51:28.147: E/BitmapFactory(5911): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@b3e145e0: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-28 16:51:28.157: I/System.out(5911): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@b3e145e0
01-28 16:51:28.407: E/BitmapFactory(5911): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@b3e31950: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-28 16:51:28.477: I/System.out(5911): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@b3e31950
```

Note: i am not getting this error while decoding the image as it is saving the scaled image to the given location without any problem using FileoutputStream, i am geting this error only if i return the bitmap to hashmap in main class.

Note: I can also give direct path in string format to the main image and it works but gives error if image is too large like bellow.
    hashmap_temp.put("image",img_path_new+"/"+cursor_receipt.getString(7)+".jpg");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleAdapter` can only bind int (resources id) or Strings.

The `bindView` implementation for `ImageView` uses the `toString` of the object as a path to the image.

What you can do is put the thumb uri `file_uri+"THUMB1_"+file_name+".jpg"` in the map instead of the Bitmap (also, it will allow a minimal number of bitmaps to be loaded at once, instead of all of them).

Change your method signature to

```
public String convertIntoThumb(String file_uri,String file_name)
```

and return :

```
return file_uri+"THUMB1_"+file_name+".jpg";
```

Comment: But it will return the original image right ?, i need the scaled image that i am getting in "bitmap" object.

Comment: what you have in `bitmap` is what you write in `fOutStream`. Therefore, what you have in this file is the scaled bitmap that you want.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake , i got it, i will try if it works, but actually i dont need to save scalled image as it will incress memmoy on sd card, i wrote fOutStream only to check if BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2); is giving that error, is there any way to show scaled image without saving it?

Comment: the other option would be to implement a custom Adapter to handle Bitmap objects.

Comment: Well, i find it hard to use custom Adapter i am new in Android programming so, but for now your answer helped me a lot, thank you so much.

Comment: Saving the thumbs to files and feeding filenames to the adapter is actually more scalable anyway, since it is much more memory-efficient.